# Why Laravel database factory not insert primary key value?

Tags: php, laravel

When inserting the customer_id to customer table using factory, it not inserting the value. The cutomer_id is the primary key of the table

Model

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';
    protected $table = 'customer';
    protected $guarded = [];
 }
```

In the test class

```
 $customer = factory(Customer::class)->create([
            'customer_id' => 1111
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key is not default 'id' and if you need to insert customer values, you should add $incrementing = false;

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';
 public $incrementing = false;
```